# Problems created in python game (while loops and more)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, do-while

I am working on a python code as I am beginner to programming. However, I have come to a halt as I am not able to find the solutions to the problems so I was hoping if someone could shine a light or guide me to tell me where I am going wrong.

Program outline:
a computer and player play against each other taking random numbers.Whoever picks the last one loses.

Here is the python programme:

```
import random  

playAgain = 'y'  

while playAgain == 'y':
    random_Number = random.randint(0-30)  

    while random_Number != 0 :  
        computer = random.randint(1,6) <= random_Number  
        random_Number = random_Number - computer  
        if random_No <= 0 :  
          print('Player 1 wins')  
        else:  
          player = int(input('Enter number'))  

       random_Number = random_Number - int(player)  

       if random_Number <=0:  
          print('Computer wins')  

playAgain== input('play again? (yes/no)')
```

The 3 problems that I am facing are:
1)The while loop does not terminate the game when I select 'no' for play again.
Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong in this area and how I can avoid this in the future for while loops.

2)If the random number remaining is 1 and if the player selects a number higher then the random number goes into negative.How can I avoid this?

3)When the random number displays 1 or 2 the computer does not select a number and so the player loses alot of the time.How can I make the computer select a number until the game does not finish?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, so we can actually read (and run) the code. As it stands, the playAgain prompt is not inside any while loop, and the whole thing is just going to raise a SyntaxError for the `print('Player 1 wins')` line, and it's hard to guess what the actual structure is supposed to be.

Comment: I have fixed the indents now and the code should run.However, even this way when I enter 'no' for playAgain the game starts again.

Comment: This still can't possibly run. `random.randint(0-30)` will raise a `TypeError`, because you're only calling it with one argument (`-30`) instead of two. Then, `if random_No <= 0 :` is going to raise a `NameError`, because you haven't defined any such variable. You have to post your actual code if you want us to help you fix a problem with it.

Comment: Also, here are some things that will not raise, but are almost certainly wrong: `computer = random.randint(1,6) <= random_Number` assigns either True or False to `computer`, which means in the next line you'll be subtracting 1 or 0 from your random number. `playAgain== input('play again? (yes/no)')` compares the input to the value of `playAgain` (`'y'`) then ignores the result. (Plus, even if you change that `==` to `=`, it won't do much good if it's not inside the `while` loop.)

Answer (score 0):

1) `while playAgain == 'y'` should be the overarching loop, as it's the thing that should execute each instance of the game. Therefore, indent everything after that one more tab/4 more spaces.

2) Change `while random_Number != 0` to `while random_Number > 0` to terminate if the value is negative. It seems to be OK for the ifs.

3) You should indent the `if` and `else` clauses right after your inner `while` loop so that they execute after each number is read. Example:

```
while random_Number > 0:
    computer = random.randint(1,6) <= random_Number  
    random_Number = random_Number - computer  
    if random_No <= 0:
        print('Player 1 wins')  
    else:
        player = int(input('Enter number'))  
        random_Number = random_Number - int(player)
        if random_Number <= 0:  
            print('Computer wins')
```

EDIT: conditional should be fixed now

Comment: I changed the while random_Number but it still allowed a negative number.